# Angular.js in Salesforce not loaded in IE9

Tags: visualforce, internet-explorer, angular

I have deployed AngualrJs and Visualforce application in SFDC,  Its working fine in IE10 , IE11 , Chrome and Mozilla, but its not loaded in IE9. I have tried this

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false"  controller="CartController">
    <!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"  lang="en-US" data-ng-app="diageoApp" id="ng-app" data-ng-controller="masterCtrl"> 
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->  
    <html lang="en-US" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"  ng-app="diageoApp" id="ng-app" ng-controller="masterCtrl" >
        <!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

`<!--[if IE 8]>` will be rendered as `<!-- ***** -->`. Therefore your IF statement doesn't work.

You can try to use `<apex:outputText value="{!'<!-- bla -->'}" escape="false" />`.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding following attributes to the page tag along with showHeader="false" sidebar="false" .

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
```